# Best way to globally change ownership of all system files/dirs belonging to user X and switching to user Y?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, terminal, server-administration

I'm taking over a Linux Ubuntu machine from a previous employee whose recently left. I've created an account for myself on the machine.

I want to preserve their home directory, but change ownership of any system files and directories outside of their home directory to myself.

Basically if User X is the previous user who has left I want to change any system files and directories belonging to User X outside of their home directory to myself now (e.g. stuff within /var/www, /usr/local etc. The only thing left that should have ownership to User X would be their home directory and anything within it. Later I can then backup anything within their home directory and then delete when ready.

Is there a known tool for such a job? Or am I looking for long piped command from the Terminal? E.g. from root, search entire file system for all files &dirs belonging to user X | chown to me? What would a long command like that look like?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the ask ubuntu not a better place to ask it?

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -user X \( -name ~X -prune -o -exec chown Y:Y {} \; \)
```

Answer (score 0):

These commands search for all files and folders which owned by the *olduser*, then change the ownership to *newuser* one-by-one.

```
find / -user olduser 2>/dev/null -exec chown newuser {} \;
find / -group olduser 2>/dev/null -exec chown newsuer {} \;
```